# Why do du/df and by System Monitor show used space in home differently?

Tags: disk-usage, coreutils, gnome-system-monitor

```
$ sudo du -h -d 0 home/
309G    home/

$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...
/dev/sda4       550G  309G  214G  60% /home
...
```

System Monitor on Ubuntu shows the used space on `/home`  is 331.1 GB

[image]

Do the different ways measure the same thing?

How differently do they make the measurements?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is two different units. The larger number is in gigabytes. 1 gigabyte = 1 billion bytes. The smaller number is in gibibytes. 1 gibibyte = 1,073,741,824 bytes = 2^30 bytes

Answer (score 1):

It's the same measurement. 309 Gb is the size specified in powers of 2 (the ugly-named *Gibibyte*), while
331 Gb is the size specified in powers of 10 according to the SI (*Gigabyte*).

309 Gb (in powers of 2) * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 = 331786223616 bytes i.e. 331 Gb (in powers of 10).

As pointed out by @don_crissti, `df -h` prints values in binary powers. If you had run `df -H`, which uses decimal powers instead, it would have printed 331 Gb of used space.

For more information, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix .